# Best pen test distro

Tags: linux, security

I have seen a lot about Back Track and was wondering if that was the best pen testing distro or if there are others that are better.

Comment: Have you considered OpenBSD? The package library has a wealth of pen-testing tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the best one I've come across - just my 2c :)

Answer (score 1):

Another one I can recommend if you do application testing is [Samurai Web Testing Framework](http://samurai.inguardians.com/). Works for me.